Merkwürdige Satzkonstruktion in Geschäftsbriefen des frühen 20. Jahrhunderts
Ich sammle eine bestimmte Art von Briefmarken, welche sich vor allem auf kurzer Firmenkorrespondenz der 1920er und 30er Jahre befinden. Dort ist mir wiederholt eine merkwürdige Form der Satzkonjunktion aufgefallen:

[1. Hauptsatz] "und" [Verb] [Subjekt] [Rest des 2. Hauptsatzes]

Diese klingt für heutige Ohren definitiv falsch und holprig. Sie ist allerdings derart häufig in Firmenkorrespondenz zu finden, dass sie entweder normaler Sprachgebrauch, stilistisches Mittel oder zumindest Konvention in Geschäftsbriefen gewesen sein muss.
Hier einige Beispiele (ich habe Ort und Jahr mit angegeben, um zu zeigen, dass es sich wohl nicht um die Eigenheit eines Dialekts handelt):

Die Expedition der Fässer ab Lager Hamburg ist durch meine
Verladestelle nach grösster Möglichkeit beschleuningt worden und kann
mich ein Vorwurf in dieser Sache wirklich nicht treffen. Ich hoffe
gern, dass die Sendung in aller Kürze an ihren Bestimmungsort
eintreffen wird und zeichne ich hochachtungsvoll [Signature] (Bremen, 1923)


Wir bestätigen Ihre Karte vom 6. d[iese]s M[ona]ts., danken für Ihre
Anfrage und sollte es uns freuen, Ihren gesch[ätzten] Auftrag zu
erhalten. Wir gestatten uns zu bemerken, dass die Preise für diesen
Artikel heute bereits wesentlich höher sind und hoffen wir gern, mit
Ihnen das Geschäft in bevorzugter Weise machen zu können. (Chemnitz,
1922)


Auf Jhrem w/Konto steht der Betrag der Rechnung vom 30. Juli noch
offen und bitte ich Sie, mir denselben bis zum 6. gefl[issentlich]
überweisen zu wollen. (Berlin, 1938)


Wir machen gleichzeitig darauf aufmerksam, dass der Ihnen gesetzte
Ausliefertermin mit dem 30. d[iese]s M[ona]ts abläuft und erwarten wir
bestimmt, dass Sie diesen Termin prompt innehalten. (Hamburg, 1921)

Dieses Phänomen hat mich neugierig gemacht. Weiß jemand etwas darüber? Hat es einen Namen? Seit wann gibt es das? Ab wann wurde es als falsch angesehen? Ist das genrespezifisch? usw.
EDIT: Changed to German as suggested.

Interesting question, and I know we're all proud of speaking English, but I fail to see the reason to ask something like this in English. People who are not able to understand this question in German will hardly be interested in it, and OTOH people with less proficiency in English are excluded without good reason.

Good point, I guess I'm just so used to asking things in English on StackExchange :-D

@halvarf Ich verstehe fast keine der Sprachen, die auf dieser Welt gesprochen werden, lese aber gerne etwas über sie. Ist das so ungewöhnlich? Den Muttersprachlern hier mag es absurd erscheinen, auf Englisch über ihre Sprache zu sprechen, aber was ist mit den anderen acht Milliarden Erdenbewohnern?

@DavidVogt Du meinst, es gibt mehr Menschen, die sich für dieses spezielle Problem der Invertierung in deutscher Kaufmannssprache interessieren, die Englisch sprechen aber wenig Deutsch, als Leute, die Deutsch sprechen aber wenig Englisch? Das glaube ich nicht. Kann es aber natürlich auch nicht beweisen...

In Aussagesätzen steht das Verb an zweiter Position.

Ich bitte Sie, den Betrag zu überweisen.

Konjunktoren wie und, oder, aber, sondern ändern daran nichts.

Und ich bitte Sie, den Betrag zu überweisen.

Eine scheinbare Ausnahme entsteht, wenn ein Adverbial des ersten Konjunkts seine Wirkung auch im zweiten Konjunkt entfaltet.

Deshalb schreibe ich Ihnen und t bitte e Sie, den Betrag zu überweisen.

Das ausgelassene deshalb ist mit t gekennzeichnet; bei einer solchen Auslassung fehlt das Subjekt, hier als e gekennzeichnet, im zweiten Konjunkt.
Von diesen Grundregeln weichen Sätze wie die folgenden in zweierlei Hinsicht ab.

Auf Ihrem Konto steht der Betrag noch offen und bitte ich Sie, ihn zu überweisen.
Wir machen auf die Ablauffrist aufmerksam und erwarten wir bestimmt, dass Sie diese einhalten.

Das erste Beispiel zeigt echte Spitzenstellung des Verbs im zweiten Konjunkt, da das Adverbial auf Ihrem Konto sich nicht auf dieses bezieht. Das zweite Beispiel zeigt, daß das Subjekt wiederholt (und nicht ausgelassen) wird.
Hermann Paul (Deutsche Grammatik IV, § 66) verbindet diese unerwartete Spitzenstellung des finiten Verbs nach und mit Kaufmannsstil und weist darauf hin, daß nach Konnektoren wie doch, entweder die Verbstellung variiert.

doch ich will davon schweigen
doch will ich davon schweigen

Die Spitzenstellung in Aussagesätzen im allgemeinen und nach und im besonderen geht zurück bis zum Althochdeutschen. Im Neuhhochdeutschen würde ich die Konstruktion als affektiert werten; von Wustmann wurde sie in seinen Sprachdummheiten scharf kritisiert.

("Die sogenannte Inversion nach und")
Auf keinem Kunstgebiete kann es ein so schlagendes Beispiel für die Verschiedenheit des Geschmacks geben wie auf dem Gebiete der Sprache die Inversion nach und. Der Beamte, der Zeitungschreiber, der Kaufmann hält sie für die größte Zierde der Rede; für den sprachfühlenden Menschen ist sie der größte Greuel, der unsre Sprache verunstaltet, sie geht ihm noch über seitens, über bzw., über selbstredend, über diesbezüglich, sie erregt ihm geradezu Brechreiz.

For an English version, check the first revision.

Schöne Quelle: "Wer hat denn zu entscheiden, was richtig und schön sei in der Sprache: der sprachkundige, sprachgebildete, mit feinem und lebendigem Sprachgefühl begabte Schriftsteller, oder der Kanzlist, der Reporter und der „Konfektionär“? Ein Schriftsteller, der die Inversion nach und aufs strengste vermieden hat, ist Lessing. Ich denke, der wird genügen." :D Die normativen Streitschriften klingen auch 130 Jahre später noch ähnlich. :D

Es scheint mir auch nur so sinnvoll zu sein, dass ein 'deshalb' im Folgesatz aus "okonomischen Gr"unden zu dieser Zeit (alles noch mit Hand oder wahrscheinlich von den Sekret"aringen mit der Schreibmaschine getippt) eliptisch weggelassen wurde, als eine Art stillschweigender "Ubereinkunft um Platz/Zeit/Porto zu sparen. [Ich bin selber erst 62 Jahre und kenne mich mit der Sprache dieser Zeit nicht aus....] Das Ph"anomen gibt's wohl auch
bei twitter.
